# Applying f to each element and return the result as list

Tags: haskell

I want that my function `someZip` returns the resulting list from applying `f` to each element.

This is what I got so far:

```
someZip :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> [(a,b,c)] -> [d]
someZip f (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs)  = f x y z : someZip f xs ys zs
```

I've tried different approaches, but I can't find a solution to this problem.
I am completly lost right now, what am I missing here?

Comment: Three lists is not the same thing as a list of triples.

Comment: Thanks @SilvioMayolo, i dont know why i have see that my signature and the targeted are incongruous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you've written and the type signature you've targeted are incongruous. If you like the type signature, you need to alter the definition

```
someZip :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> [(a,b,c)] -> [d]
someZip _ [] = []
someZip f ((x,y,z):ts)  = f x y z : someZip f ts
```

This, incidentally, can be written in terms of [`fmap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap).

```
someZip :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> [(a,b,c)] -> [d]
someZip f = fmap (\(x, y, z) -> f x y z)
```

If you prefer to keep the implementation and change the type signature, you'll need to take more arguments

```
someZip :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [d]
someZip f (x:xs) (y:ys) (z:zs)  = f x y z : someZip f xs ys zs
someZip _ _ _ _ = []
```

Incidentally, this function is actually [`zipWith3`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith3)

```
someZip :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [d]
someZip = zipWith3
```